# Prevent compiler optimization for memory access in reflashable memory area

Tags: embedded, compiler, optimization

I am working with an embedded software in which part of the software(some CONST 
config values) are reflashable, without modifying the application software. Consider the following code:

```
const uint32 Reflashable_Variable = 0;

uint32* GetAddr_Reflashable_Variable()
{
   uint32* addr;
   addr = &Reflashable_Variable; //Compiler optimizes this access to the static 
                                 //fixed address of Reflashable_Variable.   
   return addr;
}
```

The problem is that the address of `Reflashable_Variable` might vary later in the binary due to the change in size of some other parameters. What is the solution to prevent compiler from already assigning the address, rather to access the actual address of `Reflashable_Variable` during runtime? The compiler used is windriver Diab for PowerPC.

I have thought about using `volatile`, is it a good solution? Even if it is, it triggers lot of modifications in other parts of the software, so not the best for me. Is there a different possible approach?

Comment: Volatile means that the value of the variable may be changed  by an external source such as an interrupt handler. It does not mean that the address of the variable may change. C does not have a standard way of handling this, you will have to invent your own, possibly using a look-up table in a fixed area of flash.

Comment: The compiler really isn't "optimizing" access, variables don't exist in the compiled code. You should fix the addresses of these variables (and leave space between them as "reserved") or come up with a different scheme like saving the data in some kind of format that is flexible where the first part holds an address offset table.

Comment: Some machine code can use relative addressing for both code and data. (The data itself can be addressed as PC-relative in some cases if that matters to you for any reason [downloading driver code that requires driver-local static constants, for example.]) You really should study carefully your machine architecture and your requirements and find the best fitting approach that makes the most of the architecture for your usage. (That's not something I can do for you.) From your description, *volatile* isn't what you want.

Comment: Compilers can only know addresses at compile time. If the addresses change later on, you can’t rely on the compiler to know about it!

Comment: What good would it be if it did not optimize this? Instead of accessing a hardcoded address directly, it would be storing a hardcoded address into the variable 'addr' and then accessing the address stored in the variable 'addr' - which would still be hardcoded.

Comment: Instead of the variable's value you can store a *pointer* to the value in the reflashable section.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that the address of Reflashable_Variable might vary later in the binary due to the change in size of some other parameters

No, that's not a problem. The code generated by the compiler will change as well. This isn't optimization but automatic memory layout.

If your program somehow dynamically shuffles around addresses of variables in run-time, then the only sane solution is: don't do that. The solution for such scenarios, where you have EEPROM/dataflash variables which might change later, is rather to allocate every such variable to a fixed, specific address. This has to be done manually by you, in some non-standard, compiler-specific way. (gcc toolchain has `__attribute__((section...`, other toolchains have `@ 0x1234`, other toolchains use `#pragma` etc etc.)

`volatile` should be used if the *contents* of the variable may change, due to the variable being stored in on-chip EEPROM/dataflash. So you probably want to use `volatile` for that reason.

Comment: I think "part of the software(some CONST config values) are reflashable, without modifying the application software" means that the *data* is changed and flashed without re-compiling and re-flashing the program.

Comment: @JimmyB Which is fine as long as the variables are allocated at fixed addresses. Then it's your average embedded application with on-chip, memory-mapped EEPROM, simple as that.

Comment: Or you flash *pointers* to the data to fixed addresses...

Comment: @JimmyB That means the actual address of Reflashable_Variable should be accessed by 'addr = ptr2_Reflashable_Variable;' and  ptr2_Reflashable_Variable will be at a fixed location in the reflashable area.? But if I'm not wrong 'ptr2_Reflashable_Variable = &Reflashable_Variable' is still needed and will still allocate the fixed address of Reflashable_Variable, so how will it solve the issue?

Comment: @SojuTVarghese Yes, the *address* (pointer) will have to be stored at some known, fixed address in flash. You can define the pointer's location e.g. via the linker script, which you probably need to do anyway if you need a certain space/location where your updatable variables are put. Then you can either declare the pointer variable(s) to be put where you need it via the 'section' attribute, or just use a cast of the known address: uint32_t* ptr = (uint32_t*)0x1234;

Comment: @JimmyB I don't see the point of doing that unless you expect variables to wildly change type and size over time, while the number of variables will remain constant. Otherwise you are just wasting flash and creating needless complexity.

Comment: Structurally changing data, altering its type or adding new fields/variables, does not make any sense without changing the code too. That's not something you'd do by only updating the data. Modifying *arrays'* data and/or their length is pretty common, and changes to the length of one array may change the addresses of other arrays/data structures, and that's just where you use pointers (+lengths) at known addresses to dynamically handle them in code. It's much the same as normal dynamically allocated data structures at runtime, where the code cannot know the memory addresses at compile time.

Comment: @JimmyB No, modifying the length of an array stored in NVM is not common at all. I don't think I have ever had a need to do that, without changing the whole memory layout. So your pointer table smells like needless complexity to me, at the cost of increased total ROM use.

Comment: @Lundin The OP clearly states "that the address of Reflashable_Variable might vary later in the binary due to the change in size of some other parameters." - Why do you keep negating that requirement?

Comment: @JimmyB Because that's what happens if you leave the linker to allocate the variables as it pleases, instead of allocating them at fixed addresses as you should in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the data changes *structurally*, i.e. data types are changed or new fields/variables are added, the semantics of the data change and that must be reflected in changes to the code handling them.

However, if you have changes to *arrays* (including their length) or data that is opaque to the code or data which describes itself in some way, then that's a common scenario and can be handled much the same way as dynamically allocated memory at runtime.

Contrived Example (font data usually will never be updated, but):

```
// Structure describing a single glyph of a font for a certain character
typedef struct glyph_data {

  glyph_data_t* next_glyph; // Pointer to next glyph of this font, or null if this is the last glpyh

  char character; // The character which this glyph represents

  int width;
  int height;

  uint8_t bitmap[]; // e.g. width*height greyscale values

} glyph_data_t;


// Pointer to the first glpyh of the "primary font". The pointer itself is updatable as the address of that glyph may change as other (font) data gets updated.
const glyph_data_t* const PRIMARY_FONT __attribute__((section("dynamic_flash_data_entry_point")));

// Pointer to the first glpyh of the "secondary font"
const glyph_data_t* const SECONDARY_FONT __attribute__((section("dynamic_flash_data_entry_point")));


void display_primary_font() {
  glyph_data_t* current_glyph = PRIMARY_FONT;
  do {
    // e.g. display the current glyph's bitmap
    // ...
    current_glyph = current_glyph->next_glyph;
  } while ( current_glyph );
}
```

Here, the code statically only knows that there are two fonts, `PRIMARY_FONT` and `SECONDARY_FONT`. Both fonts may be updated later, so the code uses the *pointers* at known locations to find the fonts' data. Also, the set of characters supported by a font may be changed, so the font *data* includes the information how many/which characters are included as a linked list (`glyph_data_t* next_glyph`). If new characters are added, or existing ones removed, only the *data* needs to be updated. The code (and binary!) will stay the same.

Comment: `uint8_t bitmap[0];` This isn't valid C, but a non-standard gcc extension that went obsolete 20 years ago, after the introduction of VLA to the language. Anyway, this whole trick is pointless, since you wouldn't have a font table of arbitrary size in NVM, you would pick a suitable size and roll with it. Most importantly, it doesn't make any sense to store a font table in data flash, which is what this question is about. You would always store it in ordinary flash. It will be far too large to fit in most data flashes anyhow.

Comment: What's a "data flash" supposed to be? - I feel you still didn't get the point though. I agree that a font's data will likely not be updated in practice, but the principle I show is valid, useful and common. The example is to demonstrate that and how you can have fixed 'entry points' for your configuration data, which are known at compile time, so your code can work with them.  As the configuration data changes/grows, the pointers' locations remain fixed while their target is updated.

Comment: @Lundin It also shows that, especially when you have arrays, the code can definitely work with the data even when the size changes, so the request of the OP does make sense.

Comment: @Lundin This scheme also resembles (runtime) polymorphism in OOP or dynamic linking. At compile time, the addresses of functions/methods simply cannot be known, but the address and structure of the VMT is known and can be used at runtime to call code.

Comment: Data flash is the term used for emulated eeprom in MCUs, by using flash with small erase segments. It is pretty much a standard peripheral in any modern MCU. Some manufacturers call it eeprom, others data flash. If you don't know what that is, or if you have never written an eeprom driver, you cannot answer this question.

Comment: And other manufacturers don't call it either. The whole FLASH in the chip can be used for program or data and can be erased and rewritten in pages. You keep implying that the OP wants to use the comparatively small EEPROM some chips include, but that does not match the original question. Further you keep insisting that what the OP is trying to do does not make sense, i.e. updating *data* in FLASH w/o changing/recompiling the code. This shows that you do not even understand the question and hence you should probably not write an answer and should definitely not criticise others' answers.

Comment: Because storing data in program flash is a major pain and should be avoided like the plague. I've been there with Power PC specifically, when I couldn't change to a part with dedicated data flash.